# Iterate through lambdas in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, foreach, kotlin

My MVP presenter is bound to the view in onResume, so that unbinding is guaranteed. This means that sometimes, for example when data is coming from onActivityResult(), the view is not bound, but we want to still touch the view, to show progress, etc. So far I used a flag for this and executed these actions in bindView() or in updateView(), which is called when the view is bound.

Now I'm using Kotlin, so I thought what if I would use a list of lambdas for this in the BasePresenter? This is what I have so far:

```
typealias AnyLambda = () -> Unit
private val deferredActions = mutableListOf<AnyLambda>()

private val funShowProgress : () -> Unit = {
   view()?.showProgress() }

override fun updateView() {
   deferredActions.forEach { anyLambda ->
      anyLambda()
      deferredActions.remove(anyLambda)
   }
}

fun onSomethingFromActivity(x: List<Y>) {
    ...
    deferredActions.add { funShowProgress }
}
```

The problem is that the lambda is not called in forEach. If I add funShowProgress() inside the lambda, it works. Also, the lambda is there, because it runs inside forEach exactly once, but view.showProgress() is not called. What did I get wrong about lambdas?

Please note while I could call showProgress() directly from the view, I want to avoid this.

Comment: Your `deferredActions.remove(anyLambda)` probably has no effect, otherwise you'd be getting `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can't modify the list you're iterating over, except using `iterator.remove()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `add` call is wrong: it adds a lambda that evaluates the `funShowProgress` expression without any result (it doesn't call the lambda). Use either:

```
add { funShowProgress() }
```

or simply

```
add(funShowProgress)
```

Answer (score 1):

to expand yole's answer, you could also add a function reference by using `add(::funShowProgressAsFunction )` if you define the function like this:

```
private val funShowProgressAsFunction : Unit =
   view()?.showProgress()
```